# Inspect AJAX request using Chrome - remote address parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm testing 2 ajax request (simple JS and jQuery version) (the endpoint is not relevant), see code:

```js
console.log( 'SETUP: done.' );

document.getElementById( 'btn1' ).onclick =  function() {
  console.log( 'TEST' );
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open("GET", "/authors", false);
  req.setRequestHeader( 'X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
  req.setRequestHeader( 'Accept', '*/*' );
  // req.setRequestHeader( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  // req.setRequestHeader( 'Content-Type', 'application/json' );
  req.send(null);
};

jQuery( '#btn2' ).click( function() {
  console.log( 'TEST2' );
  var jqxhr = jQuery.ajax( { url: "/authors", accepts: { all: '*/*' } } )
  .done(function() {
    console.log( "success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    console.log( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    console.log( "complete" );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn1">test 1</button>
<button id="btn2">test 2</button>
```

Also on fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/0s6uc095/4/

When I inspect it with Chrome (Network tab) the 2 calls are almost equal, almost... for the jQuery request in Headers \ General I see also "Remote Address" parameter.

Is there a way to remove it from the jQuery request?
Is there a way to add it to the JS request?

(I'm in a situation where the first request works but not the second one using a FakeRest component)

Comment: (url: "/authors") try with href.

Comment: @HudsonPH: what do you mean with "href" ?

Comment: 1- if you want take the request the same page just remove this: (url: "/authors") 
2- if you take request other page you need tell: page.html, page.php... you just wrote the path

Comment: 1) if I remove the URL paramater I can't specify the API resource to fetch - 2) the endpoint is not relevant, the problem that I point remains the same